# So I'm trying to create a door that opens or slides away without an animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For the class I am in I'm trying to make a door that opens but without an animation, it plays through well in visual studios and when testing in unity the door does nothing. I'm not sure how to do this , so please  I implore any help whatsoever.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenDoor : MonoBehaviour
{
    float smooth = 2.0f;
    float DoorOpenAngle = 90.0f;
    float DoorCloseAngle = 0.0f;
    bool open;
    bool enter;



    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            enter = true;
            print("open");
        }
    }


    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            enter = false;
            print("close");
        }
    }

    void update()
    {
        if (open == true)
        {
            print("if(open)");
            var target = Quaternion.Euler(0, DoorOpenAngle, 0);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, target, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
        }

        if (open == false)
        {
            print("if(!open)");
            var target1 = Quaternion.Euler(0, DoorCloseAngle, 0);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, target1, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
        }

        if (enter == true)
        {
            print("if(enter)");
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
            {
                open = !open;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

that code should work even if it is not very safe...
Make sure that both Player and door has colliders. and the door's collider's IsTrigger option is true.